# Spring Integration auto reconnect to IBM MQ thru JBOSS Resource Adapter

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We are using Spring Integration in our project and we have a requirement where If IBM MQ goes down then we will have to auto connect to IBM MQ when it is up. We have done this implementation using `recoveryInterval` option of `org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer` class. We have given recovery interval value to try to recover the MQ connection. But it is not recovering the connection after MQ restart. Below was my existing configuration:

```
       <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="adapterId" channel="raw-channel" container="messageListenerContainer" />


        <bean id="messageListenerContainer"  class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
                <property name="connectionFactory" ref="customQueueCachingConnectionFactory" />
                <property name="destination" ref="requestQueue" />
                <property name="recoveryInterval" value="60000" />
            </bean>

    Below is the Current Connection Factory :
    <bean id="queueCachingConnectionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
            <property name="cacheProducers" value="false" />
    <!--        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" /> -->
    <!--        <property name="exceptionListener" ref="MQExceptionListener"></property> -->
        </bean>

        <jee:jndi-lookup id="queueConnectionFactory" jndi-name="MQConnectionFactory"
            expected-type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" lookup-on-startup="true"></jee:jndi-lookup>


        <jee:jndi-lookup id="queue" jndi-name="Queue"
            expected-type="javax.jms.Queue" lookup-on-startup="true"/>
```

---

```
ERROR [task-scheduler-4] LoggingHandler:145 -org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: MQJCA1019: The connection is closed.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: MQJCA1019: The connection is closed.
    The application attempted to use a JMS connection after it had closed the connection.
    Modify the application so that it closes the JMS connection only after it has finished using the connection.
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You should share `ConnectionFactory` config as well. Plus, share the logs on the matter, too. If you say "thru JBOSS Resource Adapter", maybe the issue is there, not in Spring...

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Could you please help me with the above issue

Answer (score 0):

The default message listening container should reference the caching connection factory:

```
 <!-- caching connection factory fascade, also implements exception listener -->
<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
   <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
   <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
   <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!-- this is the Message Driven POJO (MDP) -->
<bean id="messageDrivenPOJO" class="com.redhat.gss.spring.MessageDrivenPOJO" />

<!-- The message listener container -->
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
   <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
   <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
   <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER"/>                
   <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000"/>
   <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="2"/>
   <property name="messageListener" ref="messageDrivenPOJO"/>
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory"/>
   <property name="exceptionListener" ref="cachingConnectionFactory"/>
   <property name="destination" ref="jbossQueue"/>
</bean>
```